# URL rewrite with pipes and comma

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite urls from query that looks like

```
http://localhost/index.php?c=vga&av=France|originaly,540-MHZ|freq

http://localhost/index.php?c=fructe-congelate&gramaj=1+Kg&av=Romania|Tara%20de%20origine,-18%20grade|Temperatura%20de%20pastrare&brand=Royal
```

In something like :

```
http://localhost/fructe-congelate/gramaj-1+Kg/brand-royal/filtre/Romania|Tara-de-origine,-18|Temperature
```

I'm doing this for a filtering system on a shopping cart.
This is what I have for the moment in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options -Indexes 
Options +FollowSymLinks
<Files .htaccess>
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_?-]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_?-]+)/filtre/([A-Za-z0-9_?-]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1&av=$2 [NC,L]
```

All the product filters (attributes) are stored in $av, but I have predefined parameters like gramaj, brand, inoffer, page with values appended to sql query and added to the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have all kind of special characters besides alpha numerals it better to use `[^/]+` like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
<Files .htaccess>
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On 

# skip files and directories from further rules:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/filtre/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1&av=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/water/brand-([^/]+)/country-([^/]+)/filter/(.*)/?$ index.php?c=$1&brand=$2&country=$3&av=$4 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: this works just for av filter but if I add to the url &brand=$val&country=$val?

Comment: Unable to understand your comment. What is the URL are you entering in your browser and what do you want as your internal rewritten URI?

Comment: my urls can be something like : `http://localhost/index.php?c=water&brand=dorna&country=romania&av=1L|weight,mineral|type`

Comment: There is 2nd part of my question as well. What do you want as your internal rewritten URI for `http://localhost/index.php?c=water&brand=dorna&country=romania&av=1L|weight,min‌​eral|type`?

Comment: Current url: `http://localhost/index.php?c=water&brand=dorna&country=romania&av=1L|weight,min‌​‌​eral|type` and my url after rewrite shoud be : `http://localhost/water/brand-dorna/country-romania/filter/1L|weight,mineral|type`

Comment: Check updated answer now. (I will be back in an hour to check this thread).

Comment: Yes but country and brand are added dinamicaly to the url and can be just brand and av or brand and country and av or brand and country without av

Comment: I have answered thousands of questions on `mod_rewrite` but have to say that this is not making much sense to me. Why not clarify your requirements completely with examples in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58494/discussion-between-speedy-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

You may need the QSA Flag in your rewrite rule. This also routes your query string into your php script.

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_?-]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

But with that regex your pipes and commas are not included. You need to add them to the list of allowed characters:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_?-,\|]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

or your just say give me anything:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?c=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```